# How to execute SQL in Visual Studio Code on LocalHost?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, localhost, visual-studio-code

I want to execute SQL in Visual Studio Code on LocalHost. I have searched it in online for days I can't find any documentation. I found many documents to execute SQL on SQL Server but not on LocalHost.

I have installed mssql extension for Visual Studio Code. Now how can I execute SQL on LocalHost?

Comment: SQL executes on the database, not on your web server.

Comment: @SeanLange But there are other applications that can execute SQL on LocalHost Like Oracle Database Express Edition

Comment: Perhaps you mean the local database?

Comment: So have you installed SQL Server express or other SQL edition on your localhost?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, Local Database. Sorry for the wrong info

Comment: @Wendy Yes, I have SQL Server Developer edition

Comment: So connect to the server.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO I want to run It on a local database not on SQL Server because I want to execute SQL on my friend's computer also but I don't want to install SQL Server Developer. Basically, I want to use Visual Studio Code instead of Oracle Database Express Edition.

Comment: You ALWAYS connect to your database server. This is true for any DBMS. In this case the database server is instance running on your machine. If you want to run your application from your friends computer it will still connect to a sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange So only option to execute SQL in Visual Studio Code is to have SQL Server even for Local Database. Can we use Office Access as a Local Database?

Comment: I think you need to do some research on how client server applications work. Yes a local database needs to be in your DBMS. Assuming sql server then yes you have to have the DBMS installed.